# BackboneJS + RequireJS - Blurscript not working

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a backbone application where I want to use [StackBlur](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html), but somehow it doesn't work.

I use Codeigniter as backend, so in my main index page, called "home.php" in the `<body>` I have:

```
<div class="bg" data-src="demopics/bgimage.jpg" id="bgc"></div>
```

In my RequireJS config file I do:

```
paths: {
    jquery: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min',
    jqueryEffects: 'lib/jquery_effects/jquery.effects',
    all: 'lib/all/all',
    blur: 'http://www.quasimondo.com/BoxBlurForCanvas/StackBoxBlur',
},

shim: {
    backbone: {
        deps: ['jquery', 'lodash', 'less', 'jqueryEffects', 'all', 'blur'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    lodash: {
        exports: '_'
    },
    handlebars: {
        exports: 'Handlebars'
    },
    all: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    blur: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    jqueryEffects : {
        deps: ['jquery', 'all', 'blur']
    }
}
```

in my `jquery_effects.js` I have:

```
$(function() {

window.onload=function(){
//create image object
var imageObj = new Image();

    //when image is finished loading
imageObj.onload = function() {
            //get size
            var w = imageObj.naturalWidth;
            var h = imageObj.naturalHeight;

            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = w;
            canvas.height = h;
            //create virtual canvas
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            //draw the image on it
            ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);

            //apply the blur
            stackBoxBlurCanvasRGB(ctx, 0, 0, w, h, 11, 2);

            //add grey filter
            ctx.fillStyle='rgba(64,64,64,0.4)';
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);

            //and display it in 1 second using a fade
            var $canvas = $(canvas) 

            $("#bg").append(canvas);
            $canvas.show();
            var canvasRatio = $canvas.width()/$canvas.height();
            var windowRatio = $(window).width()/$(window).height();
            if (canvasRatio > windowRatio){
                $canvas.css({
                    "height": "100%",
                    "width" : "auto"
                });
            } else {
                $canvas.css({
                    "width": "100%",
                    "height": "auto"
                });
            }
            $canvas.css({
                "marginLeft" : -$canvas.width()/2+"px",
                "marginTop" : -$canvas.height()/2+"px"
            });
            window.onresize = function(){
                var canvasRatio = $canvas.width()/$canvas.height();
                var windowRatio = $(window).width()/$(window).height();
                if (canvasRatio > windowRatio){
                    $canvas.css({
                        "height": "100%",
                        "width" : "auto"
                    });
                } else {
                    $canvas.css({
                        "width": "100%",
                        "height": "auto"
                    });
                }
                $canvas.css({
                    "marginLeft" : -$canvas.width()/2+"px",
                    "marginTop" : -$canvas.height()/2+"px"
                 });
            }

};

//set the source of the image from the data source
imageObj.src = $('#bgc').data("src");

 }
```

The scripts get loaded, but nothing happens, I just get a white screen... is there an issue with `data-src` ?

Comment: jquery_effects.js attaches a function to `window.onload` but RequireJS complicates matters a bit, If it's loaded *after* `onload` fires, attaching a new event will have no effect. Can you confirm that this function actually gets executed? (e.g. set a breakpoint inside)

Comment: @kryger Sat a breakpoint inside with no effect, which apparently means that the script is not executed, so you were right! Any suggestion what to do?

Comment: anyone? placing the script inside the `<head>`-area didnt solve it...